# How does getMerge work in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I would like to know, how does the getMerge command work in OS/HDFS level. Will it copy each and every byte/blocks from one file to another file,or  just a simple file descriptor change? How costliest operation is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **getmerge**
>
> `Usage: hadoop fs -getmerge <src> <localdst> [addnl]`
>
> Takes a source directory and a destination file as input and concatenates files in src into the destination local file. Optionally addnl can be set to enable adding a newline character at the end of each file.

So, to answer your question,

> Will it copy each and every byte/blocks from one file to another file

Yes, and no. It will find every HDFS block containing the files in the given source **directory** and concatenate them together into a single file on your local filesystem.

> a simple file descriptor change

Not sure what you mean by that. `getmerge` doesn't change any file descriptors; it is just reading data from HDFS to your local filesystem.

> How costliest operation is it?

Expect it to be as costly as manually `cat`-ing all the files in an HDFS directory. The same operation for

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /tmp/ /home/user/myfile
```

Could be achieved by doing

```
hadoop fs -cat /tmp/* > /home/user/myfile
```

The costly operation being the fetching of many file pointers and transferring those records over the network to your local disk.